# OutOfMemoryException during XSL transform in .NET 1.1

Tags: xslt, out-of-memory, filestream, .net-1.1

I'm maintaining an old .NET 1.1 application that runs out of memory during an XSL transformation on a large data set. XML is written directly to a `FileStream`:

```vb
Dim xslDoc As New System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform
Dim sourceStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
Dim sourceStreamWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(sourceStream)
Try
  ' Load data and schema from DataSet
  Dim sourceDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
  dataSet.WriteXml(sourceStreamWriter , XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
  sourceStreamWriter.Flush()
  sourceStream.Position = 0
  sourceDoc.Load(sourceStream)

  ' Load XSLT
  xslDoc.Load("c:\path\to\transform.xslt")

  ' Transform (FAILS HERE)
  xslDoc.Transform(sourceDoc, Nothing, fileStream, New System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver)
Finally
  schemaStreamWriter.Close()
  schemaStream.Close()
End Try
```

I have found similar questions on the matter, but they usually describe a situation where resulting XML is written to a `MemoryStream` rather than a `FileStream`, or refer to using `XslCompiledTransform`, which unfortunately is only available from .NET 2.0 and up.

How do I avoid using up all the memory during transformation?

(Similar (unanswered) question here: http://vbcity.com/forums/t/151286.aspx)

Comment: Does it work on a small data set?

Comment: Indeed it does. It's been running fine for years, however, the data sets have never been as large as the one they are trying to process in this particular instance.

Comment: Without the code it's impossible to say, but there are lots of ways to go wrong in XSLT.  One common way to make transforms more efficient is to break them up into smaller steps to avoid duplicate traversal.  You can also use keys in come cases for the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found no way to solve this from within .NET. We may attempt to optimize the XSLT in the future.

(For now, the client has agreed to have the data split up into batches, resulting in multiple files)

Answer (score 1):

What you could try, instead of

```
Dim sourceStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
Dim sourceStreamWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(sourceStream)
Try
  ' Load data and schema from DataSet
  Dim sourceDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
  dataSet.WriteXml(sourceStreamWriter , XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
  sourceStreamWriter.Flush()
  sourceStream.Position = 0
  sourceDoc.Load(sourceStream)

  ' Load XSLT
  xslDoc.Load("c:\path\to\transform.xslt")

  ' Transform (FAILS HERE)
  xslDoc.Transform(sourceDoc, Nothing, fileStream, New System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver)
```

use

```
Dim dataDoc as XmlDataDocument = new XmlDataDocument(dataSet)
  ' Load XSLT
  xslDoc.Load("c:\path\to\transform.xslt")

  ' Transform (FAILS HERE)
  xslDoc.Transform(dataDoc, Nothing, fileStream, New System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver)
```

Comment: Interesting. However, the XSLT expects the schema to be present in the input XML (in the original code `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema` is used) which it is not when looking at the XML generated by XmlDataDocument. Is there a way to ensure that the schema is included?

Comment: @mbjdev, sorry, there is only the constructor taking the DataSet as an argument, if that does not create the contents your XSLT expects then my suggestion will not allow you to check whether it solves the memory problem. I am not sure what else you could try, in .NET 2.0 or later I would try to "get rid" of the `sourceStream` and `sourceStreamWriter` by wrapping them into `Using/End Using` before the Transform call is made but in .NET 1.1 I don't remember whether it is possible to dispose of those objects. Maybe someone else has an idea.